# batch script to grab revision number from svn

Tags: linux, batch-file, newline

I have GnuWin32 installed, so I am trying to create a batch file with linux commands to grab the revision number from SVN and write that revision number into a file. Currently I have:

```
svn info | grep -i "Revision" | cut -d" " -f2 | tr -d '\n'>> %~dp0../../Include/Version.hpp
```

However that command will always give me the SVN revision number but followed by a training new line, thus giving me the following:

```
// Version.hpp
"some revision #" << followed by a '\n'
     << a new line is here
```

I hope I have made my issue clear. Does anyone know why this happens when the command is run from a batch file and not when I execute it directly in the console? How can I fix this so that the linux commands do not append a training new line when writing the revision number to file?

Thanks for any insights.

Comment: Interesting issue.  Although probably not helpful, I did try this on a Mac with bash 3 and your technique of adding `tr -d '\n'` to the end of the pipeline before appending to the file works fine for me both from the command line _and_ in a shell script.  You might have found a GnuWin32 issue.  I don't think it has anything to do with SVN.  See if you can duplicate the problem with simple text first.

Answer (score 0):

Strange ... Maybe the trailing new line comes form the redirection. Have you tried this one:

```
echo -n $(svn info | grep -i "Revision" | cut -d" " -f2 | tr -d '\n') >> %~dp0../../Include/Version.hpp
```

However, trying on my Linux station, both solutions work fine for me! Use a native Linux system :-p !

Comment: well nothing is working guys :( i've been able to track down the issue with the "cut" command. do you guys know of a way to manipulate console input/output in dos console?